# Gradient Fill using Graphics in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica

How could I create the following using `Rectangle[]` in `Graphics[]`?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Polygon`, you can

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   VertexColors -> {White, Red, Red, White}]}]
```

Comment: And just for fun (requires a webcam to work): pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
Graphics[{Texture[CurrentImage[]], 
  Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> pts]}]

Comment: CurrentImage[] - an interesting example of a function that works so much better in the online documentation than it does on my machine... :) And how do you switch it off...

Comment: @cormullion It works pretty well here.  Try `Dynamic@CurrentImage[]`.  The very first frame it captures might be black (it needs time to adjust), and if there are several `Dynamic` ones, it gets a bit unreliable.  `ImageCapture[]` opens an UI that lets you switch it off.

Answer (score 5):

Also:

```
Graphics[Raster[{Range[100]/100}, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Red}, #] &)], 
 AspectRatio -> .3, 
 Frame       -> True, 
 FrameTicks  -> None]
```

[image]