# Conditional coloring based on a gradient

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica

Please consider :

```
Manipulate[
Row[{
Graphics[Disk[]], 
Graphics[{
 Polygon[{{0, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {0, 1}},
 VertexColors -> {White, Blend[{White, Blue}], 
 Blend[{White, Blue}], White}],
 Black, Thick,
 Line[{{i, 0}, {i, 1}}]}, ImageSize -> 300]}], 
{i, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Using Szabolcs`s solution on [Gradient Filling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142179/gradient-fill-using-graphics-in-mathematica)

How could I color the disk with the color located underneath the Black Line ?

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything specific to v.8 in this. Can any one with v.8 verify this? If not, let's remove [tag:Mathematica-8].

Comment: @rcollyer. I systematically put it so the answerers know the system I am using to adapt. Make sense ?

Comment: I understand. I'm just trying to ensure that is a v.8 specific issues, and not something I can answer. (I have v.7.)

Comment: @rcollyer. So shall I tag only Mathematica and precise that I use M8 in the question ?

Comment: Probably. Although, if you've noticed that you're using a v.8 feature, then the v.8 tag is definitely appropriate.

Comment: How can I check if I am using a V8 feature ? I have only used v8 !

Comment: In the help it says how long a function has been in mma at the bottom of the page. As an example, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140869/minimal-effort-method-for-integrating-c-functions-into-mathematica) which crosses over into v.8 territory by explicitly mentioning new features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one solution which works because the color on the left is `White` and the gradient is linear.

```
With[{max = 3, color = Blend[{White, Blue}]}, 
 Manipulate[
  Row[{Graphics[{Opacity[i/max], color, Disk[]}], 
    Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, {max, 0}, {max, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
       VertexColors -> {White, color, color, White}], Black, Thick, 
      Line[{{i, 0}, {i, 1}}]}, ImageSize -> 300]}], {i, 0, max}]]
```

[image]

---

If you had two different colors for each end (i.e., something other than `White`), the `Opacity` approach won't work. Instead, you can use the optional blending fraction argument to `Blend` the colors in the desired proportion. Here's an example:

```
With[{max = 3, color1 = Red, color2 = Green}, 
 Manipulate[
  Row[{Graphics[{Blend[{color1, color2}, i/max], Disk[]}], 
    Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, {max, 0}, {max, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
       VertexColors -> {color1, color2, color2, color1}], Black, 
      Thick, Line[{{i, 0}, {i, 1}}]}, ImageSize -> 300]}], {i, 0, 
   max}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you need to do this for a blend of colours other than something and white, `Opacity` won't be suitable. You could instead stay closer to Szabolcs' original solution using the second argument to [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blend.html) like so:

```
skyBlue = Blend[{White,Blue}];
Manipulate[ Row[{ Graphics[{Blend[{White,skyBlue},i/3], Disk[]}],  
 Graphics[{  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {0, 1}},  
 VertexColors -> {White, skyBlue,   
 skyBlue, White}],  Black, Thick,  
 Line[{{i, 0}, {i, 1}}]}, ImageSize -> 300]}],  {i, 0, 3}]
```

I have divided `i` by 3 because that parameter is meant to vary between `0` and `1`.

[image]

Comment: *sigh* I just can't type fast enough.

Comment: oooh... I addressed this in an edit that was just 1 second _before_ yours! :)

Comment: I can delete again - you at least have pictures. But I think it's got to the point that I will stop answering questions. Given my time zone and the other things on my plate, it is almost impossible for me to answer a question that you, Leonid, Sjoerd, Mr.Wizard or belisarius - sometimes more than one of you - haven't already answered more thoroughly.

Comment: It's sometimes helpful to have more than one answer, though, or more than one "let's see where this approach goes". There are different styles of solution, and beginners such as myself find the view from various angles interesting...

Comment: @cormullion That's what we normally do here. In this case, they were identical, hence Verbeia's comments above.

Comment: @Verbeia, Since we both had the same answer, I'd be more than willing to fix the small `{}` errors in yours, upload a screenshot to it and rollback my answer :)

Comment: Please don't stop posting.  You have already added a lot of interesting things, and I am sure you could continue to do so.

Comment: @yoda - very kind of you to offer and now I see the `{}` typo, I do need to fix that. I don't know enough about gardening to join you over there. But now you know how I got the Marshal badge - I started reviewing when there were no questions I could decently answer here that hadn't already been answered the same way by someone else. I normally look at SO over my morning coffee at the office, but my Mma is at home, so I don't generally have time to answer the ones that need a bit more research.

Comment: @Verbeia I've fixed the typo for you. I also changed the second `Blend` color to the actual color instead of `Blue` (would've been much darker otherwise) and uploaded a screenshot for you :) Feel free to rollback if you would rather I didn't edit it.

Comment: @Verbeia Rep points are a nice game, but learning is nicer. Please don't quit answering. I enjoy your posts a lot.

Comment: @belisarius - please don't read this as being about rep points. It's just about not finding many cases where any answer I can think up wouldn't be a duplicate of an existing answer.

Comment: I agree with @cormullion, being able to show the variety of the possible solutions is a good thing. Consider [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7437144/198315) where there were 4 different answers, and none of them used the same methods. Occasionally, we miss and post the same thing. Oh well.